# Horizontal UICollectionview cells not on top

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal `UICollectionview` with deafult layout.

The `UICollectionViewCell` is almost the height of the `UICollectionview`.

The thing is that the cells are aligned to the bottom and not the top. How come?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: it's all in the storyboard...

Comment: Sometimes Xcode can add header section by default, which can look like just black or transparent padding. Look does you disabled it in UICollectionView properties.